# BitmapImage in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, bitmap, bitmapimage

I am porting .NET Framework project to .NET Core 2.0 but I have struggles with the BitmapImage class. I know that BitmapImage in .NET Framework is part of PresentationCore assembly but in .NET Core I could not add any of these. Also, I have searched for a package that supports it but could not find any, too. In .NET Framework it is part of System.Windows.Media, but there is no such package for .NET Core.

Do you have any ideas how I can solve this issue?

Comment: BitmapImage is for XAML applications. Are you writing a XAML application? Note that `System.Drawing.Bitmap` is available.

Comment: Yes, a WPF application and I need the BitmapImage. I have successfully added the System.Drawing but which resolves the Bitmap class but not the BitmapImage one.

Comment: I don't think WPF is supported. [See this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/784#issuecomment-320271668)

Comment: The WPF is on .NET Framework. I am refactoring the controller that is being called from a .NET Framework project and .NET Core project.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't support this. What is it you're trying to do? There may be other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

System.Drawing is now ported to .Net Core so you should be able to get access to that reference. Here is some 3rd party libraries that have implemented it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/